# how do i change my https to http with a command line in terminal?

Tags: http, https, command-line

I used a command line to change http to https but now i want to undo this,
but i cant find the right command line, or is there anotherway ?

I already tried this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTP=true&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. The config you posted indicates it is set to use HTTP, not HTTPS (and only works for Windows). Is it you want to change it the other way round? From HTTP to HTTPS? Then you could change the part `"set HTTP=true&&react-scripts start"` to `"set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"` with an editor. Another option is to look for a `.env` file in the root of your npm project.